# module be2net not loaded with define parameter in /etc/modprobe.d/

Tags: linux, linux-networking, kernel, rhel6, kernel-modules

I want to load the `be2net` module with the parameter `rx_frag_size` set to `4096`, the default value being `2048`.
As specified by the [documentation](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0106342) I created a file `/etc/modprobe.d/be2net.conf` with the content `options be2net rx_frag_size=4096`.

However after the reboot, the `rx_frag_size` is still set to 2048 (checked with command `cat /sys/module/be2net/parameters/rx_frag_size`).

I tried to find any script that would `modprobe be2net` in `/etc/` without success.

I also tried [this method](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-persistent_module_loading) and put an executable script `/etc/sysconfig/modules/be2net.modules` to load the module using `modprobe be2net rx_frag_size=4096` and did not work either, the parameter remains at 2048.

As last method, to verify if the file `/etc/modprobe.d/be2net.conf` is used by modprobe, I unloaded the module be2net and reloaded it using

```
modprobe -r be2net
modprobe be2net
cat /sys/module/be2net/parameters/rx_frag_size
4096
```

so actually it works but this is not persistent.

Do you have any idea what would cause the module not being loaded with the parameter set in `/etc/modprobe.d/be2net.conf` at boot?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules that are loaded in the initramfs need to have their module options copied to the initramfs, otherwise they'll be loaded with their defaults.

To resolve this problem requires [regenerating the initramfs](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1958). You can do this on RHEL 6 and later by running:

```
dracut -f -v
```

This regenerates the initramfs for the running kernel. To regenerate the initramfs for all installed kernels, add `--regenerate-all` to the command.